# Do this will call finally?

Tags: c#, try-catch, finally

suppose that i have this code. if exception is InvalidData, do this will call finally to clean resources.

```
while(CanWork){
            try
            {
                 ....
            }
            catch (InvalidDataException e)
            {
                LogAction(false, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogAction(false, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (insta != null)
                {
                    insta.Disconnect();
                    insta.Dispose();
                    insta = null;
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: "Finally" block will always call, whether you got exception or not.

Comment: i mean in first catch i break the while, and before break will call finally?

Comment: `using` would probably be a lot easier, note, but simple answer: "yes"

Comment: Multiple answers have been given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will, but not when it is about to leave the while, but just after the code in the `try or catch` is done executing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course . `finally` block always gets executed . Please refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details

Comment: be careful with "always" - there are a range of scenarios where it won't be; ok, those are pretty pathological scenarios where the process is very sick - but they are genuine. More simply: if the power switches off it won't run `finally`

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please let me know the all such range of scenarios or refer a link , it will be very very  helpful for me

Comment: scenarios involving thread-abort, or fast exit, possibly certain security exceptions or out-of-memory scenarios; things like that - the nasty ones